# Celery example throws error on local machine

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery

I'm trying to run the most basic, very first [celery example](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application) on my local Windows machine. I copy it here for convenience:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

The instructions then go on to explain that the Celery worker server can be run in the command line as follows:

```
$ celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO
```

When I try to do this however I get an error:

```
>celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO

 -------------- celery@LAPTOP-JUAE71NA v5.0.5 (singularity)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0 2021-02-05 15:02:32
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x1ca182463d0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 16 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . tasks.add

[2021-02-05 15:02:33,218: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 18264 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,218: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 17784 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,218: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] child process 15608 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,218: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 20200 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,218: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 16168 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,234: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] child process 19544 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,234: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] child process 10932 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,249: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-8] child process 1084 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,249: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-10] child process 11376 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,249: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-11] child process 16868 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,249: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-9] child process 18404 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,249: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-13] child process 17992 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,249: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-12] child process 19364 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,265: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-14] child process 11604 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,265: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-15] child process 8216 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:33,265: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-16] child process 5844 calling self.run()
[2021-02-05 15:02:34,958: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)

[2021-02-05 15:02:39,033: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Trying again in 4.00 seconds... (2/100)

[2021-02-05 15:02:45,147: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Trying again in 6.00 seconds... (3/100)
```

I don't understand why this happens. Is the string passed to the optional `broker` argument in the Celery class generic or should I be adapting it for my local machine? I know nothing about RabbitMQ or brokers in general so I'm not sure how I can fix this.

Comment: This celery needs broker for messaging and backend for storing information. Broker can be Rabbitmq and backend can be redis. It looks the broker you are trying to use is not accessible by celery. So can you provide more info on this ?

Comment: How can I make it accessible to celery then?

Comment: What broker are you using ? Do you have rabbitmq, redis anything installed

Comment: https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/task-queue-celery-rabbitmq/  
Refer to this link for using celery with broker

Comment: @SantoshBalaji in the link you provide I'm seeing that they recommend installing `rabbitmq-server` using `sudo`. However I am using a windows machine with `miniconda` for my python environment

Comment: You can follow installation for windows then.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html

Comment: But can I limit rabbitmq to my current conda environment? I would prefer not to do a system wide installation....

Comment: You can use docker instead. I am not sure with conda environment

Answer (score 0):

flask + celery + redis + windows. After a day I got it working (not factory yet).

Launch worker with eventlet flag (`pip/pipenv install eventlet`)

`celery -A app.celery worker -P eventlet --loglevel=info`

also celery did not like my `localhost`, so I had to put `127.0.0.1` instead:

`'broker_url': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379', 'result_backend': 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'`

Got the setup saved in [repo](https://github.com/yomajo/Flask-Celery-Redis-Windows/commit/d30cc772564b36add10153053f5898f1413fd05c).